# Is the sequence $ \frac{1}{10^n} $ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

I must prove that $ f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}; n \to\frac{1}{10^n} $ is a convergent sequence. I thought:

If $f$ is convergent then $\exists L \in \Bbb{R}(\forall \epsilon >0 (\exists m \in \Bbb{N}(\forall p \geq m (|\frac{1}{10^p} - L|<\epsilon))))$, therefore:
$|\frac{1}{10^p} - L|<\epsilon$ then $ \frac{1}{10^p}<L+\epsilon \wedge \frac{1}{10^p}>L-\epsilon$, but $10^p\neq 0, \forall p \in \Bbb{N}$ then $ L>\frac{1}{10^p}-\epsilon \wedge L<\frac{1}{10^p}+e$, but I can't continue now! Thanks in advance!

Comment: it converges to 0. firstly, it is monotonically decreasing and also, it is bounded(it can't be negative, so 0 is the bound).

Comment: @user99323, thanks.. I thought also: $10^p> 0, \forall p \in \Bbb{N}$ then $10^p=|10^P|\to +\infty$, therefore $\frac{1}{10^p} \to 0$. Is correct?

Comment: yes, that's the same thing - 10^n is indefinitely increasing, so its reciprocal will be decreasing, but it can't decrease beyond 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $a_n=\frac{1}{10^n}$, it is clear that the sequence converges to $0$. So Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, we need to find a $n_o$ such that $\forall n\ge n_o$, we have

$|\frac{1}{10^n}|\lt\epsilon \implies \frac{1}{\epsilon}\lt10^n$.

Since we are dealing with $\epsilon\in(0,1)$(As it is obvious that for $\epsilon\gt1$, $n_o=1$), Taking logarithm both sides gives $\log_{10}(1/\epsilon)\lt n$. Then Choose $n_o=\lceil \log_{10}(1/\epsilon)\rceil $.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to unpack your set grammar for better readability. Regardless, for given $\epsilon > 0$, let $n \geq M = \lceil{}{\log 1/\epsilon} \rceil{}$. Then, 
$$
\left| \frac{1}{10^n} - 0 \right| = \frac{1}{10^n} \leq \frac{1}{10^M} = \frac{1}{1/\epsilon} = \epsilon.
$$
So, it follows that the limit of the sequence $\left\{ \frac{1}{10^n} \right\}_\mathbb{N}$ is 0.